# Update trigger assistance

Tags: sql, oracle

Evening, needing assistance regarding triggers.

Within my development environment I have two tables, one containing employee data (which contains various data errors that will be amended via ALTER TABLE) and the log table.

How do i go about designing a trigger that will update multiple rows contained within the log table such as 'issue_status','status_update_date' when ALTER TABLE sql is used to amend the data contained in the first data table?

-- employee table

```
 CREATE TABLE emp(
emp_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
emp_name    VARCHAR(30),
emp_postcode    VARCHAR(20),
emp_registered  DATE,
CONSTRAINT  pk_emp PRIMARY KEY (emp_id));
```

-- SQL for the log table

```
    CREATE TABLE data_log
    (issue_id NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
    table_name VARCHAR2(20),
    row_name VARCHAR2(20),
    data_error_code NUMBER(2),
    issue_desc VARCHAR2(50),
    issue_date DATE, 
    issue_status VARCHAR2(20),
    status_update_date DATE);
```

-- example log insert

```
    INSERT INTO data_log( SELECT DI_SEQ.nextval, 'emp', emp.emp_id, '1', 'emp_name case size not UPPER', SYSDATE, 'un-fixed', '' FROM emp WHERE emp_name != UPPER(emp_name));
```

This is the example of the issue inserted into the log table. All i want to do is if I update the emp table to set 'emp_name' to Upper the trigger will register this update and change the rows 'issue_status' and 'status_update_date' to 'fixed' and the 'sysdate' of when the change was made

I've done some browsing however i'm still struggling to understand, any literature recommendations would be appreciated also.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: `alter table` modifies the schema, not the data. Are you actually looking to log schema changes, or are you actually using `update`/`insert` and not `alter table`?

Comment: Also, please tag your RDBMS.

Comment: I'm wanting to log any updates/inserts that occur to the employee table in to the log table, so yeah ignore the alter table that was an error on my part.

Comment: Ok, well.. how far have you gotten? do you have a `create trigger`? This question is pretty broad as it stands now.

Comment: You can [edit] your question, code formats much better that way. Can you do that, and also mention what the problem with that code is? Also - are you using SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, ..?

Comment: I've made the edit and i'm using ORACLE

Comment: My issue is that I'm unsure how to format my trigger to get my desired outcome

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle myself, but I've added the tag - hopefully someone else will come along. I guess your trigger code needs to set `issue_status` to 'fixed' for rows which have the 'emp_name case size not UPPER' description, but no longer have `name <> upper(name)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that we don't use `ALTER TABLE` to update the rows of a table as you have mentioned.We use `Update` statement. Your `trigger` should be a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER` like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_emp_upd BEFORE
    UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.emp_name = upper(old.emp_name) )
BEGIN
    UPDATE data_log
        SET
            issue_status = 'fixed',
            status_update_date = SYSDATE
    WHERE
        row_name =:new.emp_id;

END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much